# Laravel - DataTable Localization

Tags: laravel, datatable, localization, translation, multilingual

Morning,
I'm building a multilanguage site with Laravel.
Changing of display language is OK, when user select language (fr or en).
But only DataTable options are not translated (search, previous, ...).
I can translate it into Datable {language:..}  but this method is static.
Thks for your help !

Comment: If you used Yajra DataTable read the question answer in github : https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1418

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing for the datatable,
You can use laravel lang function and blade syntax for mixing php into script ,
to do that,You can use laravel lang function for `language` property for dynamic localization
Here is sample for:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu":"{!!__('dataTable.menu')!!}",
        "zeroRecords": "{!!__('dataTable.zeroRecord')!!}",
        ....

    }
} );
```

And in `resources/lang` folder in your laravel project, create correspond php file array for your desired languages

For more information about laravel localization check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization)